# AngularJS Material Design element's attributes not working

Tags: angularjs, material-design

first time using material design with angular and something is not going right I think.

I'm using the `md-tab` element and everything is fine until I add the `md-border-bottom` as in this example in the docs of AngularJS MD : https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.tabs

the bottom border just won't appear.
here's my template:

```
<md-tabs md-border-bottom>
    <md-tab ng-repeat="league in leagues" label="{{league.caption}}">
       {{league.caption}}
    </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

and here is the output : http://screencast.com/t/OZrD9xFlQA

I want to mention that this is not the only MD attribute that is not working for me, i assume I've done something wrong, or I'm missing something.

Here is the css and js I linked to my html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css" />
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The line on the border appears to come from this CSS rule:

```css
md-tabs[md-border-bottom] md-tabs-wrapper {
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

That's in *docs.css*, which means it's a style provided specifically for the documentation, not to *all* consumers of the library. If you want a border, you'll have to apply the style yourself.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I thought it is provided with the MD. Thank you mate.